# how to have single distinct col. with multiple selection in sql server

Tags: sql-server, distinct

here i am selecting many col. but i want only
`x.PurchaseOrderNumber` to be distinct. i have used

```
SELECT  disctinct(x.PurchaseOrderNumber), x.DateRaised AS DateRaised,
       LEFT(x.Description, 100) as Description, x.TotalValue, x.SupplierName,   
       x.POStatus,  
       x.TenantRecharge, x.JobActivity, x.BuildingName, x.BuildingID,
       x.ReferenceNumber, x.PaymentStatus , x.ACCTNUM, x.TotalCost
```

but it does not serve the purpose

i have even used

```
 group by x.PurchaseOrderNumber
```

but it for that i have use aggregated function which i don't want to
use !!

my code

```
SELECT  x.PurchaseOrderNumber, x.DateRaised AS DateRaised, LEFT(x.Description, 100) as Description, x.TotalValue, x.SupplierName,   
  x.POStatus,  
   x.TenantRecharge, x.JobActivity, x.BuildingName, x.BuildingID, x.ReferenceNumber, x.PaymentStatus , x.ACCTNUM, x.TotalCost  
  FROM  wsm_View_PODashboardList AS X
  INNER JOIN dbo.wsm_WorkOrder_PurchaseOrder wp ON wp.PurchaseOrderNumber = X.PurchaseOrderNumber
  INNER JOIN dbo.wsm_WorkOrderSchedule wo ON wo.WONumber = wp.WONumber
  where X.POStatus  in ('Created','Authorised','Sent','Matched')  
and wo.WOStatus in ('New Request','Delayed','Scheduled','Work In Progress')  
and wo.EstCompletionDate <= getdate ()  
and wo.siteid in (select wsm_ContactSite.siteid from wsm_ContactSite where wsm_ContactSite.contactid = @ContactID)  ORDER BY X.DateRaised DESC
```

Comment: You can't. Not directly, at least.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using a [common table expression](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175972.aspx) with **[`row_number()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186734.aspx)** you can get the row that contains to the most recent `DateRaised` for each `PurchaseOrderNumber` like so:

```
;with cte as (
select  
    x.PurchaseOrderNumber
  , x.DateRaised as DateRaised
  , left(x.Description, 100) as Description
  , x.TotalValue
  , x.SupplierName
  , x.postatus
  , x.TenantRecharge
  , x.JobActivity
  , x.BuildingName
  , x.Buildingid
  , x.ReferenceNumber
  , x.PaymentStatus 
  , x.acctnum
  , x.TotalCost
  , rn = row_number() over (
    partition by x.PurchaseOrderNumber
    order by x.DateRaised desc
    )
from  wsm_View_podashboardList as X
  inner join dbo.wsm_WorkOrder_PurchaseOrder wp 
    on wp.PurchaseOrderNumber = x.PurchaseOrderNumber
  inner join dbo.wsm_WorkOrderSchedule wo 
    on wo.wonumber = wp.wonumber
where x.postatus  in ('Created','Authorised','Sent','Matched')  
  and wo.wostatus in ('New Request','Delayed','Scheduled','Work In Progress')  
  and wo.EstCompletionDate <= getdate ()  
  and wo.siteid in (
    select wsm_ContactSite.siteid 
    from wsm_ContactSite 
    where wsm_ContactSite.contactid = @Contactid
    )  
)
select 
    PurchaseOrderNumber
  , DateRaised
  , Description
  , TotalValue
  , SupplierName
  , postatus
  , TenantRecharge
  , JobActivity
  , BuildingName
  , Buildingid
  , ReferenceNumber
  , PaymentStatus 
  , acctnum
  , TotalCost
from cte
where rn = 1;
```